# Why does Julia BigInt iterative functions overflow?

Tags: recursion, format, julia, overflow, biginteger

Let's say I want to write the factorial function in Julia in the following recursive way:

`FACTORIAL(n) = n==1 ? 1 : n*BigInt(FACTORIAL(n-1))`

Doing so, it shows the following error when trying to compute `FACTORIAL(1e6)`:

```
julia> FACTORIAL(1e6)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] FACTORIAL(n::Float64) (repeats 65428 times)
   @ Main ./REPL[36]:1
 [2] top-level scope
   @ REPL[38]:1
```

However, one may easily see that `factorial(BigInt(1e6))` does not throw an overflow error.

1. I wonder what is wrong with the recursive code that results in such an error?
2. Is there a way to write such a function recursively which avoids such an error?

Note that my question is general and **not** about the factorial function by itself. I have seen such a behavior with a few other functions written recursively.

Comment: a stack a million frames deep? or did you think Julia would optimize this recursion?

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow is easy to fix by changing recursion to a loop.

```
function FACTORIAL(n)
    res = 1
    for i in 1:n
        res *= i
    end
    return res
end
```